# Adding more than one explanatory variable to Logistic Regression (glm) model gives an error?

Tags: r, glm

I've tried to fit the following linear model:

```
ad.glm.all <- glm(WinLoss ~  Score + Margin + Opposition + Venue + Disposals + Marks + Goals + Behinds + Hitouts + Tackles + Rebound50s + Inside50s + Clearances + Clangers + FreesFor + ContendedPossessions + ContestedMarks + MarksInside50 + OnePercenters + Bounces+GoalAssists, 
                  data = ad.train, family = binomial)
```

And every time I try to run this code I get the following error message:

```
glm.fit: algorithm did not convergeglm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

And when I look at the summary for this regression model I get:

```
Call:
glm(formula = WinLoss ~ Score + Margin + Disposals + Marks + 
    Goals + Behinds + Hitouts + Tackles + Rebound50s + Inside50s + 
    Clearances + Clangers + FreesFor + ContendedPossessions + 
    ContestedMarks + MarksInside50 + OnePercenters + Bounces + 
    GoalAssists, family = binomial, data = ad.train)

Deviance Residuals: 
       Min          1Q      Median          3Q         Max  
-2.980e-05  -2.100e-08   2.100e-08   2.100e-08   3.569e-05  

Coefficients:
                       Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)          -8.578e+00  2.502e+06   0.000        1
Score                 4.194e+00  5.165e+04   0.000        1
Margin                2.187e+00  3.742e+03   0.001        1
Disposals             8.946e-02  3.549e+03   0.000        1
Marks                 1.427e-01  1.938e+03   0.000        1
Goals                -2.288e+01  3.082e+05   0.000        1
Behinds              -7.034e+00  5.482e+04   0.000        1
Hitouts               3.640e-02  5.167e+03   0.000        1
Tackles               8.939e-01  7.075e+03   0.000        1
Rebound50s           -2.064e-01  8.497e+03   0.000        1
Inside50s             5.645e-01  8.133e+03   0.000        1
Clearances           -1.930e-01  1.525e+04   0.000        1
Clangers             -2.040e-01  1.056e+04   0.000        1
FreesFor             -7.699e-01  1.762e+04   0.000        1
ContendedPossessions -5.752e-01  7.424e+03   0.000        1
ContestedMarks       -1.869e+00  1.069e+04   0.000        1
MarksInside50         6.742e-01  1.676e+04   0.000        1
OnePercenters         1.616e-01  6.888e+03   0.000        1
Bounces              -8.763e-01  7.669e+03   0.000        1
GoalAssists           7.570e-01  3.299e+04   0.000        1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1.2540e+02  on 91  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 7.1154e-09  on 72  degrees of freedom
AIC: 40

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 25
```

Obviously something is going seriously wrong here, right? My P values for each variable can't all just be 1, and my Z values all 0; right?

I gave it a Google and the best I could find was someone suggesting that the error might be due to having too many variable (which would make sense given how many variables I have). So I got to work deleting them, one by one, and I would **still** get the error every single attempt up until I only had one variable (x ~ y); only then would I get no error.

Can someone explain to me what this error might mean? And why all my P-values are 1 and z values 0?

Thanks in advance!

-Troy

Comment: Looks to me like a crass example of overfitting. You might want to try LASSO/elastic net. Also have you checked if one of your predictors causes already perfect seperation?

Comment: @Roland I'll have a look into LASSO/elastic net, guessing they're just packages you can add to R to deal with this sort of thing? And I'm guessing that because it's sports data and I'm looking at winning/losing that the 'Margin' variable would probably be a perfect separator; any suggestions for checking for sure though?

Comment: well what is _score_?

Comment: Make a contingency table of your dependent vs that predictor.

Comment: UPDATE: I think I figured out why the glm was being so weird; not enough data. As I'd split my data into their various different teams I had about 20 rows of data in my training set and 5 rows in my test set (for each team). Combining all the teams together into one big data frame gave be 18x those numbers. And I'm pretty sure that's the reason I'm not getting weird errors anymore. Thanks for your help lads.